# automatically thread a function on call

Tags: java, multithreading

How can I automatically thread a function when it is called in Java ?
In Python I would do:

```
def threaded(func):
    def wrapper(*_args, **kwargs):
        t = threading.Thread(target=func, args=_args)
        t.start()
        return
    return wrapper

@threaded
def function_to_thread():
    #blah
```

How can I do this or something similar in Java ?

Comment: Have you searched how to create a thread in java?

Comment: Try `new Thread(() -> function_to_thread()).start();`